# function declaration error - Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following issue in my angular2 application.

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
>   expected.

For the implementation I followed following project.

https://github.com/Vintharas/angular2-step-by-step-06-consuming-real-data-with-http/blob/master/app/people.service.ts

I am not sure why I am getting above error in my code. I coded according to the code available in the github link above. Below screen capture will show where the error is appearing.

[image]

As you can see, the keyword function has been red underlined by the IDE. I really cannot see a syntax issue in my code.(I am from a Java background and this is my first Angular app)

Kindly point me out what is wrong here and how to correct it.

This is my complete code:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Tender } from './models/Tender';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class TendersService {

    private _endpointUrl: string = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/get-all";

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    getAllTenders(): Observable<Tender[]> {

        console.log("get all tenders in service");

        let tenders = this._http
            .get(this._endpointUrl)
            .map(mapTenders)
            .catch(handleError);

        console.log('tenders.service.ts -> retrieved tenders = '+tenders);
        return tenders;
    }

    function mapTenders(response: Response): Tender[] {
        console.log('tender.service.ts -> mapTenders');
        return response.json().map(toTender);
    }

    function toTender(r: any): Tender {
        console.log('tender.service.ts -> toTender');
        let tender = <Tender>({
            id: r.id,
            name: r.name,
            description: r.description,
            category: r.category,
            district: r.district,
            town: r.town,
            imageUrls: r.imageUrls,
            referenceNumber: r.referenceNumber,
            addresses: r.addresses,
            telNos: r.telNos,
            dateTimePosted: r.dateTimePosted,
            lastUpdateOn: r.lastUpdateOn
        });
        console.log('Parsed tender in service :', tender);
        return tender;
    }


    function handleError(error: any) {
        let errorMsg = error.message || `Yikes! There was was a problem with our hyperdrive device and we couldn't retrieve your data!`
        console.error(errorMsg);

        // throw an application level error
        return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
    }

}
```

Comment: The message says it all. Declare your functions out of the class (like your example does), or make them methods of the class. You can make them static methods if they don't need access to `this`.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you. Don;t know y i could not see it. However, what is the logic there? I am not familiar with the functions outside the class. Aren't methods and functions same in Angular2 ?

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with that. The language is called TypeScript. And, in that matters, it obeys the same rules as EcmaScript. No, a method and a function are not the same thing. A method is tied to this. A static method is tied to the class where it's defined. The functions have nothing to do with the class. They're completely independant. So why should they be declared in the class?

Comment: I've updated your tags for you;  I removed Angularjs, since that is a completely different framework from Angular2.  I also added the typescript tag, because this question appears to be about typescript specific syntax.

Comment: @Claies thank you very much

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please point me to a beginner level tutorial to learn about functions and methods. Can I declare those functions in a separate file? can I call the functions from other classes?

Comment: No, I can't. You can call the functions from anywhere in the same module (i.e. the same file). Or you can export them, just as you're doing with your class, and use them everywhere else by first importing them (just like you're doing to import Tender from another module)

Comment: that is harsh :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, declare functions inside of methods, outside of classes, or as class properties (and in some other places), but not as direct children of classes. Direct children of classes must be constructors, methods, accessors, or properties.

Here is an example; the compiler allows all of the following function declarations.

```
class SomeClass {

    foo = function() { };

    someMethod() {

        function bar() { }

    }
}

function baz() {  }
```

It is worth [fiddling around with TypeScript play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20SomeClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20bar()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Afunction%20baz()%20%7B%20%20%7D) and [working thru the offical JavaScript to TypeScript tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html).